# Hibernate 3 null exception, join fetch query

Tags: mysql, hibernate, nullpointerexception, hql, hibernate3

I have an issue with a search query.

My model:

Project:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "project")
public class Project {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
        name="project_tag",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="project_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="tag_id")
    )
    private Set<Tag> requiredSkills;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "short_description", columnDefinition="TEXT")
    private String shortdescription;

    @Column(name = "extended_description", columnDefinition="TEXT")
    private String extendedDescription;
}
```

Tag:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tag", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"name"})})
public class Tag {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    public int hashCode() {
        return getName().hashCode();
    }
}
```

I want to search projects with some search string, and I want to find projects with this string in the name, short description, extended description, AND tags.
Searching for tags is the problem.

Here is my query:

```
public List<Project> search(String search) {
        search = "%" + search + "%";
        Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(
                "from Project p" +
                " left join fetch p.requiredSkills r" +
                " where p.name like :search" +
                " or p.shortdescription like :search" +
                " or p.extendedDescription like :search" +
                " or r.name like :search"
                );
        query.setParameter("search", search);

        query.setMaxResults(30);

        return (List<Project>) query.list();
    }
```

The line "or r.name like :search" is giving me an error (everything works fine without it):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    myProject.model.Tag.hashCode(Tag.java:53)
```

I get this error only when some projects are found (no error when no results returned).
Any ideas? Thanks!

Edit: forgot to tell that projects may have 0 to n tags...

Comment: Why don't you show us the real code? The error is a `Tag.hashCode()`, yet your Tag class doesn't have any `hashCode()` defined.

Comment: hashcode() method is implemented. If I show you the whole code, you will cry. Yet I can add the hashCode() method, it's true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I just deleted the "fetch" keyword from JB Nizet's proposed query, and it worked...

Final query:

```
Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(
            "select distinct p" +
            " from Project p" +
            " left join p.requiredSkills r" +
            " where p.name like :search" +
            " or p.shortdescription like :search" +
            " or p.extendedDescription like :search" +
            " or exists(select r2 from Project p2 join p2.requiredSkills r2 where p2.id = p.id and r2.name like :search)");
```

Might be related to https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateFAQ-AdvancedProblems#I_have_a_nonlazy_set_of_entities_that_override_equals_and_Hibernate_throws_a_NullPointerException saying that this problem will not be corrected...

Edit: tried again with fetch, it worked... Don't understand why!

Answer (score 1):

Given the code and the exception, this means that you have a tag without name: `getName().hashCode()` throws a NullPointerException, so `getName()` returns null.

That said, your query is a dangerous one, because it returns projects with a partial list of their tags. You should rewrite the query as

```
select p from Project p
left join fetch p.requiredSkills r
where p.name like :search
or p.shortdescription like :search
or p.extendedDescription like :search
or (exists(select r2.id from Project p2 
           inner join p2.requiredSkills r2
           where p2.id = p.id and r2.name like :search))
```

Comment: Btw, currently I only have 1 project and 2 tags related to it in the database, each one has a not null name.

Comment: exists(select r2.id from...) instead of exists(select t.id) I guess. Anyway, this leads to an error "MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'tag5_.id' in 'field list'",

Comment: The query ends with: or exists (select tag5_.id from project project3_ where project3_.id=project0_.id and (tag5_.name like ?)), seems that inner join is not working

Comment: Sorry. I fixed the query (well, I hope so...).

Comment: So, the error with the corrected query is that:

java.lang.NullPointerException
 at.ac.tuwien.qse.ase.ideafactory.model.Tag.hashCode(Tag.java:52)
    java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:389)
    java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:217)
 java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:322)
 org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet.endRead(PersistentSet.java:352) - The same as before

Comment: Is it possible that it comes from the left join "fetch" ?

Comment: I just deleted the "fetch" and it works now... Why can't we use fetch? Maybe I didn't really understand what it does

Comment: fetch is used to load the projects with their skills, in a single query, instead of just loading the projects, and waiting for the sills collection to be accessed to load them lazily.I really don't understand how the hashCode could throw this exception if the name is not null.